# jQuery Mobile page blank when following direct link

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I will use this link http://m.smo.uhi.ac.uk/en/colaiste/smo40/ to illustrate the problem.

If I go to this link directly, it displays a blank page. The browser gets the HTML correctly (view source), but jQM does not load it into the  after it processes it - it just inserts an empty  as a child (inspect element).

If I go to this link though the home page http://m.smo.uhi.ac.uk/en/ -> click The College -> click SMO@40 - the page displays correctly.

The validator returns no relevant errors, and the page seems to be valid jQM page comparing it to the information on jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html 
I get no errors in the console.

I have tried different version of jQuery but it makes no difference. My guess is that is it something really simple, since I am new to jQM.

Can anyone spot why the page is not loading when linked directly?

Comment: The problem was not strictly related to direct links, but rather I had a conditional not outputting the starting <body> tag on certain pages. In case jQM returns a blank page, triple-check your markup and don't trust the validator 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you watch carefully you will notice your direct link don't have opened BODY tag. If you add it your page will be shown successfully.

Also jQuery Mobile is using only a page content (its logic will disregard missing BODY tag) so this will not cause a problem when linked from internal jQM page.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I wonder why the validator did not pick up on that... you'd think that a missing <body> tag is invalid.