# $.ajax function not called after clicking <a> link

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and I'm in dealing with a problem:

I have 2 html pages: index.html and page.html

```
//index.html
...
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
<div id='contents'></div>
</body>
...

//script.js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
      ...
       success:
       $("#contents").html(content_to_display).trigger('create');
       ...
   });
});
```

and another page that calls the previous

```
//page.html

...
<body>
<a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-role="button">Back</a>
</body>
...
```

the problem is that when I click on the Back button (after refreshing the page.html), the page index.html is displayed correctly, except the  that stays empty unless I manually refresh the page (`F5` or `Ctrl+R`) displaying the content I want to be displayed.

how to load the `index.html` page without manually refreshing the page every time?

Comment: Could you show us how you are showing the backbutton? Is it with data-add-back-btn="true" or with $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn= true;
    });

Comment: the back button: it's just as you see, plain html. a simple <a> tag

Comment: are you using just  <!DOCTYPE html> ? and the code validates?

Comment: yes. I use doctype. what u mean for code validates?

Comment: Validates as in it has all the correct <meta>, the </div>,</ul> ect... all close... that type of stuff.

Comment: yes, the html tags are all valid. I think it's a matter of jquery...see the @EliteOctagon answer. is it write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh is your problem, this is a timeline of what have happened:

1. **`index.html`** is loaded
2. page is changed to **`page.html`** and its body content is loaded into **`index.html`**  **`DOM`** but link is still **`domain/page.html`**
3. Because of full page refresh, **`page.html`** is reloaded without a **`HEAD`** content of **`index.html`**.
4. page is changed to **`index.html`** and its body content is loaded into **`page.html`**  **`DOM`** WITHOUT its **`HEAD`** part and that is a reason why javascript is not triggered

This problem will be fixed if both **`index.html`** and **`page.html`** have identical **`HEAD`** content, mainly reference to the same custom js file. For more solution to this problem (with solution) take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**, to be more transparent it is my personal blog. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806954/1848600)**.

Comment: I do have the same head contents. except that index.html and page.html have different references to different js files in the body not in the head

Comment: If you want, send me your full example to my email and I will fix it for you.

Comment: email sent. sorry for the italian language

Comment: Can you send it once more, I didn't received it. My mail:   dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Comment: I am on it, give me 15-30 min.

Comment: I have made necessary changes, please take a look and tell me is this it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     // stuff do do before the window is unloaded here.
 }
```

this runs before the user is navigated away from the current page.

this means you can force the user to navigate to your page which will refresh correctly.

Comment: it doesn't work. I edited my previous question. The issue appears only if I refresh the page.html page and after I click on Back. If I don't refresh the page.html before the click, the index.html page is displayed correctly...

Comment: ah, maybe I understand what you say... you are saying to move the js include on the page.html instead of index.html? so that the jquery loads the contents of the index.html before it lefts the page.html page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the backbutton if you are just navigating back one page:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">BACK</a>
```

Or give this a shot:

```
$.mobile.changePage(href, {changeHash: false });
```

Comment: already tried. it's the same thing... it's a matter of jquery.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502807/jquery-mobile-page-blank-when-following-direct-link or try this in the js: $.mobile.changePage(href, {changeHash: false });

Comment: also, are you looking at this in Chrome or FF or a more modern browser?

Comment: I tried both $.mobile.changePage(...) and change the browser. same results (except that I can for example assign the transition effect to the page :-) )